# <a name> causes content to be pushed up

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have set a tag name at the top of the 'comments' section, with

```
<a name="comments"></a>
```

I go into this by the following:

```
<a href="page-on-my-site#comments">Comments</a>
```

Going into the page in any other way works fine, if however I use this ' a tagname', all the content is pushed up.

Take a look on my site for clarity: http://www.cristianrgreco.com/

For the top article, pressing 'Read more' works fine, if however you click on '2 Comments' it focuses on the comments, but pushes the content up.

This has never happened to me before so I really have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it happens because the contents of `#content_wrapper` get scrolled.

Comment: i was hoping it would just scroll the page down to that section, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by combination of `overflow:hidden` and scrolling.  You will need to make a few changes:

First change

```
<a name="comments"></a>
```

to

```
<a id="comments"></a>
```

Add the css rule below so that it is actually positioned in the right place on your page:

```
#comments{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Remove `overflow:hidden` from `#content_wrapper` and add it to `#sidebar_wrapper` instead.

Comment: I have only 1 word for you.. GENIUS! Completely fixed, thanks!